# Why is my transaction with a really high gasPrice pending?

Tags: gas, gas-price, gas-limit

I have created a transaction on the Polygon mainnet with a gasPrice of 496 GWEI (this is 496 times more than the normal gasPrice) and a gasLimit of 2,000,000.

The transaction is a simple ERC20 transfer(), so shouldn't require more than about 50,000 gas.

Why is my transaction stuck on pending with such a high gasPrice and gasLimit?

https://explorer-mainnet.maticvigil.com/tx/0x48038a06e15be665b21cfad5d06c8f4f496a17ef80cede470b4760b070db774f/internal-transactions

Comment: Have u changed the nonce of ur tx ?

Comment: If ur tx has the nonce 18 and ur account has just 7 transactions.. then that tx cannot be mined until the missing transactions form 8 to 17 are mined. I’m not sure if that is the problem, can see anything useful using my phone

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip nonce numbers when making transactions. From what I can tell the nonce of that account is 4. Try performing that transaction again but with the correct nonce(i.e nonce 5).